# Foreign key constraint not working

Tags: mysql, sql, foreign-key-relationship

I have created two tables with the following data

[image]

Script:

```
CREATE TABLE Persons
(
P_Id int NOT NULL,
LastName varchar(255) NOT NULL,
FirstName varchar(255),
Address varchar(255),
City varchar(255),
PRIMARY KEY (P_Id)
)ENGINE=InnoDB;

CREATE TABLE Orders
(
O_Id int,
OrderNo int,
P_Id int NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (O_Id),
FOREIGN KEY (P_Id) REFERENCES Persons(P_Id)
ON DELETE CASCADE
ON UPDATE CASCADE
)ENGINE=InnoDB;

INSERT INTO Persons VALUES
(1, 'Last', 'First', 'Address', 'City');

INSERT INTO Orders VALUES
(1, 2, 1);

DELETE FROM Persons WHERE P_Id = 1
select * from Orders;
```

I have implemented this example in MySQL workbench (example taken from w3schools).

Now on deleting the first row in the persons table, even the corresponding row from the Orders table is supposed to get deleted. i.e., the last row. But it is not getting deleted.

Can someone tell me what i am missing here ?

Still it shows the row in orders table.

Comment: Are the engines for both tables InnoDB?

Comment: I think you have to specify it with ON DELETE CASCADE. (if using INNODb, otherwise I dont know)
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/innodb-foreign-key-constraints.html

Comment: i have added InnoDB, even now it does not work

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As stated in the comments, you should turn on `foreign_key_checks`:

```
SET foreign_key_checks = 'ON'
```

> If set to 1 (the default), foreign key constraints for InnoDB tables are checked. If set to 0, they are ignored.

[See the documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_foreign_key_checks)

Comment: even now its not reflecting

Comment: How would you ever model an optional relationship?

Comment: @ArunAbraham Then you're doing something else wrong. The demo works.

Comment: I have done the exact demo in mysql workbench. But after everything  when i do select * from orders; i can still see the row with values.

Comment: Then check if your server is ignoring them: `SHOW VARIABLES like 'foreign_key_checks';` If it returns OFF, turn it on by using `SET foreign_key_checks='ON';` If that does not work either, try everything afresh using the command line client. Then you can troubleshoot your MySQL workbench settings.

Comment: [I have made it so the columns are not identical, and it works fine](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/21e59/1/0), unless I'm missing something (which is likely possible, SQL Server developer here.)

Comment: There is no requirement that a foreign key column must be defined as NOT NULL when the referenced column is NOT NULL.

Comment: @AarolamaBluenk You are wrong on this one. (did you check that your [demo works with `NULL` too](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/21e59/2))?

Comment: @ypercube You're right. I think my confusion was with referencing a `NULL` column. I've updated my answer.